# Length of circular slide

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

There is a cylindrical tower with a slide which is wound uniformly around the tower exactly 5 times. The height is 50 m and the circumference is 8 m. I'm trying to find the length of the slide.

I'm wondering if this is related to trigonometry. If that's the case, how do I use it? Is there any other way of solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to cut the cylinder along a vertical line at the beginning of the slide.
[image]

Comment: So it was related to Pythagoras.... Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To the answer given by Seyed I would mention that this can be done as the cylinder and the plane are (locally) isometric, but maybe you don't need that much detail. It roughly means that if you cut the cylinder along a vertical line and lay it flat then lengths are preserved.